# PySpark udf returns null when function works in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a user-defined function that takes a cumulative sum of an array and compares the value to another column.
Here is a reproducible example:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

# instantiate Spark
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# make some test data
columns = ['loc', 'id', 'date', 'x', 'y']
vals = [
    ('a', 'b', '2016-07-01', 1, 5),
    ('a', 'b', '2016-07-02', 0, 5),
    ('a', 'b', '2016-07-03', 5, 15),
    ('a', 'b', '2016-07-04', 7, 5),
    ('a', 'b', '2016-07-05', 8, 20),
    ('a', 'b', '2016-07-06', 1, 5)
]

# create DataFrame
temp_sdf = (spark
      .createDataFrame(vals, columns)
      .withColumn('x_ary', collect_list('x').over(Window.partitionBy(['loc','id']).orderBy(desc('date')))))

temp_df = temp_sdf.toPandas()

def test_function(x_ary, y):
  cumsum_array = np.cumsum(x_ary) 
  result = len([x for x in cumsum_array if x <= y])
  return result

test_function_udf = udf(test_function, ArrayType(LongType()))

temp_df['len'] = temp_df.apply(lambda x: test_function(x['x_ary'], x['y']), axis = 1)
display(temp_df)
```

In Pandas, this is the output:

```
loc id  date        x   y   x_ary           len
a   b   2016-07-06  1   5   [1]             1
a   b   2016-07-05  8   20  [1,8]           2
a   b   2016-07-04  7   5   [1,8,7]         1
a   b   2016-07-03  5   15  [1,8,7,5]       2
a   b   2016-07-02  0   5   [1,8,7,5,0]     1
a   b   2016-07-01  1   5   [1,8,7,5,0,1]   1
```

In Spark using `temp_sdf.withColumn('len', test_function_udf('x_ary', 'y'))`, all of `len` ends up being `null`.

Would anyone know why this is the case?

Also, replacing `cumsum_array = np.cumsum(np.flip(x_ary))` fails in pySpark with error `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'flip'`, but I know it exists as I can run it fine with Pandas dataframe.
Can this issue be resolved, or is there a better way to flip arrays with pySpark?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: flip takes 2 arguments, seems you have not provided axis for it

Comment: @Sri_Karthik Second argument is optional; [numpy flip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html)

Comment: @Sri_Karthik Turns out I needed to upgrade pyspark to 2.4.4 from 2.4.3 - seems to work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since test_function returns integer not List/Array. You will get null values as have you mentioned wrong return type. So please remove "ArrayType from udf" or replace return type as LongType() then it will work as given below. :

Note: You can optionally set the return type of your UDF else the default return type is StringType.

Option1:

```
test_function_udf = udf(test_function) # Returns String type
```

Option2:

```
test_function_udf = udf(test_function, LongType())  #Returns Long/integer type

temp_sdf = temp_sdf.withColumn('len', 
           test_function_udf('x_ary', 'y'))
temp_sdf.show()
```

Comment: that worked, but I sure don't understand why it worked. Can you explain?

Comment: Hi Kai, please refer the test_function . The test_function returns integer type not List. Hence Mentioning Array Type will return null values.  Please refer my edited answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get back `Ljava.lang.Object;@612e71a4` or `null`. I'm using spark 3.2.1

Comment: can you give me sample function how you are writing